# Bit operations on Enum

Tags: c#, enums, bit, bitwise-operators

I'm having some problems with the following:

- I want to get the first visible AND frozen column of a column collection.

I think this will do it:

```
DataGridViewColumnCollection dgv = myDataGridView.Columns;
dgv.GetFirstColumn(
     DataGridViewElementStates.Visible | DataGridViewElementStates.Frozen);
```

- Is it also possible to make a bitmask to get the first frozen OR visible column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation is, AFAIK, "all of these" - it uses:

```
((this.State & elementState) == elementState);
```

Which is "all of". If you wanted to write an "any of", perhaps add a helper method:
(add the "this" before `DataGridViewColumnCollection` to make it a C# 3.0 extension method in)

```
    public static DataGridViewColumn GetFirstColumnWithAny(
        DataGridViewColumnCollection columns, // optional "this"
        DataGridViewElementStates states)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in columns)
        {
            if ((column.State & states) != 0) return column;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Or with LINQ:

```
        return columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
            .FirstOrDefault(col => (col.State & states) != 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, bitmasks usually work like this:

`|` is joining flags up. `&` is filtering subset of flags from a flag set represented by a bitmask. `^` is flipping flags by a mask (at least in C/C++).

To get the first frozen OR visible column `GetFirstColumn` must handle bitmasks different way (e.g. `GetFirstColumn` could get the first column that matches any of the flags set, but this is not the case).